# create multiple csvs for same values in 1 column using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I am new to Python and so need help with creating multiple csvs from 1 csv for a value in 1 column.
My original csv file sample below. The original file is 1000 lines big.

```
Path                              FolderName    FolderOwner    EmailAddress
\\A\folder1\subfolder1\file1      folder1       Roy            Roy@gmail.com
\\A\folder2\subfolder4\file7      folder2       Roy            Roy@gmail.com
\\A\folder3\subfolder11\file9     folder3       Jack           Jack@gmail.com
\\A\folder4\subfolder13\file12    folder4       Jack           Jack@gmail.com
```

For above example I want to run a for loot to create 2 new csv files for FolderOwner = Roy and Jack. In original csv file I got 50 FolderOwners.
Once I have these CSV files, I want to send automatic email to the owners using EmailAddress folder, but that's part 2.

First I need a python script with for loop to automatically create 2 csv files for Roy and Jack.

I have below script, but for it I need to give FolderOwner manually, which is hard for 50 owners.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv ('originalfile.csv')
df2 = df1[df1.FolderOwner == 'Roy']
df3 = df2['Path', 'FolderName', 'FolderOwner']
df3.to_csv('Royfile.csv')
print(df3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
df1 = pd.read_csv ('originalfile.csv')

for fn in df1.FolderOwner.unique():
    (df1.loc[df1.FolderOwner.eq(fn),
             ['Path', 'FolderName', 'FolderOwner']].to_csv(f'{fn}file.csv'))
```